# Get Page's Type from URL in C#

Tags: c#, .net, url-routing

Given a URL, I have to be able to know what the page's Type is that resides at that URL. For example, lets say I have a couple pages.

```
//first.aspx
public partial class FirstPage : System.Web.UI.Page { }

//second.aspx
public partial class SecondPage : MyCustomPageType { }
```

I would like to be able to call a method in the following manner with the following results:

```
GetPageTypeByURL("first.aspx");     //"FirstPage"
GetPageTypeByURL("second.aspx");        //"SecondPage"
```

Is this possible? How can I do this?

Comment: The type of `FirstPage` is `FirstPage`. The type of `SecondPage` is `SecondPage`. You are looking for the type they directly inherit from.

Comment: That's not possible by observing the page by URL from the outside. **Why** would you need this - I'm sure there is a better way

Comment: @Oded Good point. I will update my question.

Comment: @BrokenGlass You're right. This is pretty unusual and I recognize that. I am trying to be able to infer some properties of certain parts of the sites to customize the site's navigation. It is a legacy site I am working on and I'm trying not to rewrite large portions of the site to accommodate the new functionality I am adding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1591506/707979), it appears that you can get the class of a specific page. You may then be able to use reflection to determine its base type. (Note: I haven't attempted this, it's just a suggestion.)

```
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(Me.Request.Url.AbsolutePath)
```

Comment: Wow. I really wasn't holding out hope that this was possible but this seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
public Type GetPageTypeByURL(string url)
{
    object page = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(url, typeof(object));
    return page.GetType().BaseType.BaseType;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Type pageType = GetPageTypeByURL("~/default.aspx");
```

Comment: This looks really promising, but Rob's answer is a little bit cleaner. I'm going to have to check out the `BuildManager` class a little more. Looks like it does some pretty interesting things.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: 
I assume that you calling the page from some other program.
Get the HTML, search for your distinguishing HTML / hidden element that tells you what the page is.
If you are on the server just load up the page as a text file and read it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Page page = (Page)System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(url, typeof(Page));
CustomerPage page = (CustomerPage) SomeMagicalPageCreater.CreatePage("CustomerPage.aspx");
```

https://forums.asp.net/t/1315395.aspx
 This is what I found.

Comment: Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question

Comment: Also, what is `SomeMagicalPageCreater`?

Comment: Hello, please elaborate the answer, you can read [answer] to get advices. Thanks